# Search in all records but return only parent products and no sub products, Laravel5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

A store products and their sub products in  one table. 
Product will have a self-reference on 'parentId'. If it's not a sub-products then parentId is NULL and there is only 1 level nesting, so sub-products don't have sub-products.
I want to implement search query that searches all the records but it returns parent products. So if search for a term that matches a sub-product it got it's parent products. 
This is my current query:

```
$products = Product::with('categories')
            ->where('is_active', '=', 1)
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search_term%")
            ->where('brand', 'LIKE', "%$search_term%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%$search_term%")
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->where('parent_pid', '=', 'NULL')
            ->get();
```

Comment: try this `whereNotNull('parent_pid')` instead of this `->where('parent_pid', '=', 'NULL')`

Answer (score 0):

The way you filter your products with

```
->where('parent_pid', '=', 'NULL')
```

does simple string comparison and checks if **parent_pid** column contains string **NULL**.

If you want to filter all products that have **NULL** value in this column, you need to use **whereNull** method:

```
->whereNull('parent_pid')
```